# Symfony2 need some clearness and guidance with a shopping cart (regarding the quantities)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

So I have a shopping cart. I can add, delete and view the products in the cart. The problem now comes with increasing and decreasing the quantities. If for example the user wants to buy more than one of the same product.

BACKGROUND:

There are two ways on how you can increase your quantity:

You can increase it every time you add a product from its details page. This part works and im doing this like here:

```
if( isset($cart[$id]) ) {

            $qtyAvailable = $product->getStock();

                if ( $qtyAvailable > $cart[ $id ]) {
                    $cart[ $id ] = $cart[ $id ] + 1;
                } else {

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cart'));
            }


        } else {
            // if it doesnt make it 1
            $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
            $cart[$id] = 1;
        }
```

What is the **$cart** here?

AS you can see I am checking if the id of the product already exists in the cart. If it does then increase its value. My array Cart only has one key which is and id of the product and I increase the ids value everytime I add the same product.

The other way is to increase the quantity in the cart itself with the buttons +,-. I am stuck at this part.

I am guessing there are two ways I can increase the quantity here, either by using javascript or writing the similar function like on the top(i prefer this one). Since I am not used to javascript the only way I think i can do this is by writing this:

```
<div class="input-append"><input class="span1" style="max-width:34px" placeholder="{{ key }}" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16" type="text">
<button class="btn" type="button" name="add" onclick='javascript: document.getElementById("appendedInputButtons").value++;'><i class="icon-minus"></i></button>
<button class="btn" type="button" name='subtract' onclick='javascript: document.getElementById("appendedInputButtons").value--;'><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
```

However this only changes the number on the screen, it doesnt increase or decrease in the array itself. Maybe there is a way you can change the array values with javascript?

**UPDATE**

Ok so I am trying to understand the code one of the StackOverflow users have provided, however I am getting some problems.

So in my twig I have made this:

```
<div class="input-append"><input class="span1" style="max-width:34px" name="quantity" placeholder="{{ key }}" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16" type="text" data-id="12">
                    <button class="btn" type="submit" value="increase"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus"><i class="icon-minus"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
```

Then in my controller i done like in the example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/cart/update", name="cart_update")
 */
public function cartUpdateAction( Request $request )
    {
        $response = new JsonResponse();
    $requestData = $request->request->all();
    $productid     = $requestData['product'];/** first put all validations not empty/ is numeric and exists in your db etc*/
    $quantity = $requestData['quantity'];/** first put all validations not empty/ is numeric etc */
    /** if all is good then put your logic*/
    $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->find($productid);
    $qtyAvailable = $product->getStock();
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $cart = $session->get('cart', array());

     if ( $qtyAvailable > $cart[ $productid ] ) {
        $cart[ $productid ] = $cart[ $productid ] + 1;
        $response->setData(array('success'=>true,'message'=>'Qunatity increased'));
    } else {
        $response->setData(array('success'=>false,'message'=>'Out of stock'));
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Now I am having problems on where do I have to write the javascript code? I read that you have to create a new .js file and add it with assetic, so I did it like this:

I have added the jquery library and my ajax script file to assets in my base.twig.html file like this:

```
{% block javascripts %}

            {# Le Javascript #}         
                {% javascripts 


                    'bundles/mpFrontend/assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'         
                    'Mp/ShopBundle/Resources/js/scripts.js'   
                    %}      
                    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>       
                {% endjavascripts %}
```

And then I extend the base.html.twig in the twig that I want to use the ajax.
However nothing happens when I press the button. SO the ajax code is added wrong probably?

Comment: To update whole cart i suggest you to build a form and provide user a submit button once user sets the quantities  of item then he/she should submit the form on server side code validate each item and update their quantities accordingly

Comment: That sounds better but what if I have a specific template and I need to increase the quantities the way i described in my post?

Comment: If you need to change the quantity on user action like on plus sign click then you need to make an ajax call each time user presses +/- and this ajax request will post the item id and quantity to server on server side use your login or reuse your existing code

Comment: Can you push me towards the right direction with the code? I have never used ajax before..

Comment: You need to include jquery library first  then your js file which contains ajax code see sample demo for js only [`demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/bc5dr1ph/) in demo it successfully picks product id and its quantity , its a third party site so i can't provide ajax demo

Comment: I have added the library and my script files however I am still not getting anything on button click. This is so confusing for me.

Comment: You have to first start with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and how and when to use then cover [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) part :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to pick and post values to server you have to include the library first in order to use .

sample markup will be each item has its own container one input either text or hidden if you are using any js effect to increment quantity  make sure this input gets updated each time increment or decrement action performed by user

```
<div class="item">
    <input type="text" data-id="product id here" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus">+</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">-</a>
</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
```

initialize click handler for anchor with class plus so that you can post values to server to update your cart array

```
$('.plus').on('click', function (e) {
    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'server side action url here',// /cart/update 
        async: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {product: $this.parent('.item').find('input').data('id'),quantity: $this.parent('.item').find('input').val()},
        success: function (data) {
          if(data.success == false){
           alert('error')
          }
        }
    });
});
```

On your server side action just a sample code for increment quantity if you get the idea you can implement same for decrement scenario

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; /** At the top of your controller*/
/**
 * @Route("/cart/update", name="cart_update")
 */
public function cartUpdateAction( Request $request ) {
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $requestData = $request->request->all();
    $productid     = $requestData['product'];/** first put all validations not empty/ is numeric and exists in your db etc*/
    $quantity = $requestData['quantity'];/** first put all validations not empty/ is numeric etc */
    /** if all is good then put your logic*/
    $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->find($productid);
    $qtyAvailable = $product->getStock();
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
    if ( $qtyAvailable > $cart[ $productid ] ) {
        $cart[ $productid ] = $cart[ $productid ] + 1;
        $response->setData(array('success'=>true,'message'=>'Qunatity increased'));
    } else {
        $response->setData(array('success'=>false,'message'=>'Out of stock'));
    }
    return $response;
}
```